# Entity Framework: Navigation Property from a service

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

A few of my Db tables have been moved outside my database, their data is now available to me through a API call. So in the `Student` class below, the `Subject` table has been moved out, I still have the `SubjectId` with which I have to query the API and get the Subject data.

```
public class Student
{ 
    public Subject Subject { get; set; }
}
```

Is there anything I can do with EntityFramework through which I wont have to change my code, and accessing the Navigation property `student.Subject` would query my API for the data and return it back to me?

Comment: if you create the instance you can access . Your question is not clear ........

Comment: When we write student.Subject, it fetches the data from the database in EF, what I want is that instead of that, it fetch the data from a service API

Comment: if you have access the api you can install EF and write query over there

Comment: The data for Student is going to come from our own DB using Entity Framework, but the Subject thing comes from an API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the easiest thing to do is to mark the Subject Property as **[NotMapped]** so EF will not try search for the DB Table

And then Write your Property **get** to Query the API. 
That will cover the functionality you want.

```
    public class Student
    {
        [NotMapped]
        public Subject Subject { get {
            return QueryAPIHere(this.SubjectId);
        } set; }
    }
```

And if you want to avoid calling the API Every time you access the property you can store it in a private variable

```
    [NotMapped]
    private Subject _subject
    public Subject Subject
    {
        get
        {
            if (this._subject == null)
                this._subject = QueryAPI(this.SubjectId);
            return this._subject;
        }
        set;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Anestis, I will try that